# Find or Initialize By Parameter Confusion Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameter-passing

I'm trying to use 'find_or_initialize_by' in my orders controller.  I need to find the record by two parameters, user_id and item_id.  If that particular order combination doesn't exist then I would like to create it.

Here is what I have in the orders controller:

```
def create
    @order = Order.find_or_initialize_by(#not sure of syntax here)
      @order.update_attributes(quantity_requested)
        @order.save
          redirect_to :back
end
```

I've tried many different parameters and all produce error messages.  Can anyone please clarify the correct way to pass parameters here?

Thank you for any and all help.

Edit to add more code:

db schema:

```
create_table "orders", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.integer  "quantity_requested"
    t.boolean  "order_completed"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
```

Order model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user 
    has_one :item, dependent: :destroy
    validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

Item show:

```
<%= form_for Order.new do |f| %>
   <%= f.number_field :quantity_requested, value: 0, max:  @item.quantity, min: 1, class: "item-quantity form-control", :onclick =>  '$(this.form).submit()'  %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_or_initialize_by` takes two parameters. The first is a hash, and the second is a block to be used if nothing is found and is instead initialized. If you don't need the block, you can just do:

```
@order = Order.find_or_initialize_by(user_id: value, item_id: value)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  My confusion lies in what to pass in for the value.  All of the examples pass in something concrete like "2" or "bob" but I just want the user_id of the current user and item_id of the item page they are on passed in as the value.  Is that possible?

Comment: Sure. Do you have the `current_user` method (usually provided by Devise)? What is the route you are posting to? Does it have an item id in it?

Comment: Yes, I have a current_user method.  Right now it is posting to /orders(.:format)  orders#create.  It should have an item id because I associated the item and order model (order has one item, item belongs to order) and have item_id .  Please let me know if I can help more and thanks again for helping.

Comment: For the user id, you could do `user_id: current_user.id`. Based on what you say, it's not clear to me how you know the item id an order is supposed to be associated with. Is there a specific item on the page you are posting from? If so, you could post the item id with the `params`.

Comment: The params for the item id get rid of all error messages, but the item id still isn't recording to the db.  I edited the question to add more code bc I think it will help.  I understand if you don't have time to look.  Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Add `<%= f.hidden_field :item_id, @item.id %>` to your form. Then you'll have access to the item id in `params[:order][:item_id]`.

Comment: Thanks, I had that hidden field and took it out bc I thought it was part of the problem, but turns out I had an error in params.  Thanks a ton!